# Partial ToC in 'The Legrand Orange Book' too long and does not wrap around

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, templates, books, parts

I'm writing a textbook with "The Legrand Orange Book" template. A `\part` is very long and it can not be produced on a single page.

So, the initials chapters/sections are cut as shown in the figure.

**Is there anybody that know how to modify the template for very long TOC?**

**I would like split the TOC in more pages when is needed.**

Here are an example of code that reproduce my problem:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.3 (8/8/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
\draw (current page.center) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

\part{Part One}

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}
\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}
\section{Citation}\index{Citation}
\section{Lists}\index{Lists}
\section{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}
\section{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}
\section{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\chapter{In-text Elements}
\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}
\section{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}
\section{Notations}\index{Notations}
\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}
\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}
\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}
\section{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}
\section{Examples}\index{Examples}
\section{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}
\section{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}
\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}
\section{Problems}\index{Problems}
\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

\chapter{Presenting Information}
\section{Table}\index{Table}
\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\section{Articles}
\section{Books}

\chapter{Text Chapter}
\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}
\section{Citation}\index{Citation}
\section{Lists}\index{Lists}
\section{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}
\section{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}
\section{Descriptions and Definitions}

\chapter{In-text Elements}
\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}
\section{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}
\section{Notations}\index{Notations}
\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}
\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}
\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}
\section{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}
\section{Examples}\index{Examples}
\section{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}
\section{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}
\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}
\section{Problems}\index{Problems}
\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

\chapter{Presenting Information}
\section{Table}\index{Table}
\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\section{Articles}
\section{Books}

\end{document}
```

This is the minimal whole file `main.tex` of the template [The Legrand Orange Book](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book). The bug is in page 7.

[image: TOC of the code above]

**UPDATE**

In the file `structure.tex` the command `\part` is strongly modify. The code is this one:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
    \fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
    \node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
    \printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
    }};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-13.8cm,-2cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
    \fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-13.8cm,-2cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Ok! Wait a minute, please.

Comment: This is not the index, it's the Table of Contents (ToC) and nobody that does not have `structure.tex` can compile this.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer, but the problem is the same. ;-) Do you know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: In a MWE, you should not use any files to which no one other than you has access. This is also true for images. Instead of images like `background` or the like use `example-image` or `example-image-a` to `example-image-c`.

Comment: The problem with those messy templates is that one has to go over and over to template or whatever website to get the newest versions. If they would be on CTAN, they would be shipped out with every update of TL or MikTeX (provided one updates quite often)

Comment: Maybe I have understood, I have to try to do it by myself. ;-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni: I think I could track the error to the nested `tikzpicture` environment in the redefined `\@part` macro in `structure.tex`

Comment: Also in my opinion. Now I have indented the code of "part headings". I have seen this code in a tikzpicture enviroment: `\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);`. Maybe this `rectangle` define the maximum area of the TOC. But the code go far, far away my knowledge of tikz.

Comment: Emm... I have tried to do it. :-( I post the code in the question.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni `tikzpictures` cannot be broken across pages - my suggestion is to use another mechanism to generate the part toc, there are several packages capable to do this, for example the `minitoc` package.

Comment: @samcarter: I've got an idea ... not counter-related, however ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `structuretcb.tex` modified with `tcolorbox` being breakable and placing the `tikz` content nodes in an overlay, however, it will add two empty pages after the minitoc of the `\part`. I don't know where this comes from, I place this as a preliminary 'solution' only:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% Structural Definitions File
% Version 2.0 (9/2/15)
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
% 
% This file has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS REQUIRED PACKAGES AND CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customize lists
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce spacing between bullet points and numbered lists

\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts

\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]

% Boxed/framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}% % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

% Non-boxed/non-framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenum}% % Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square
\makeatother

% Defines the theorem text style for each type of theorem to one of the three styles above
\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\theoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
\newtheorem{theoremeT}[dummy]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exerciseT}{Exercise}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumex}
\newtheorem{exampleT}{Example}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumbox}
\newtheorem{vocabulary}{Vocabulary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definitionT}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollaryT}[dummy]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{ocrenum}
\newtheorem{proposition}[dummy]{Proposition}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEFINITION OF COLORED BOXES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

% Theorem box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{tBox}

% Exercise box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}    

% Definition box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt]{dBox}    

% Corollary box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=gray,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{cBox}

% Creates an environment for each type of theorem and assigns it a theorem text style from the "Theorem Styles" section above and a colored box from above
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{tBox}\begin{theoremeT}}{\end{theoremeT}\end{tBox}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}                 
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}   
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}        
\newenvironment{corollary}{\begin{cBox}\begin{corollaryT}}{\end{corollaryT}\end{cBox}}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REMARK ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{remark}{\par\vspace{10pt}\small % Vertical white space above the remark and smaller font size
\begin{list}{}{
\leftmargin=35pt % Indentation on the left
\rightmargin=25pt}\item\ignorespaces % Indentation on the right
\makebox[-2.5pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[draw=ocre!60,line width=1pt,circle,fill=ocre!25,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] at (-15pt,0pt){\textcolor{ocre}{R}};\end{tikzpicture}} % Orange R in a circle
\advance\baselineskip -1pt}{\end{list}\vskip5pt} % Tighter line spacing and white space after remark

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,code={\thispagestyle{empty}},halign=right,left skip=5cm,nobeforeafter,frame hidden,
        remember,
        overlay={%      
        \fill[ocre!20] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
        \node at ($(current page.north east)+(-3cm,-2cm)$){{\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
        \node at ($(current page.north west)+(4cm,-3.25cm)$) {\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\thepart};}]
 \printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}   
\end{tcolorbox}
}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}
```

`main.tex`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.3 (8/8/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\input{structuretcb} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
\draw (current page.center) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

\part{Part One}

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}
\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}
\section{Citation}\index{Citation}
\section{Lists}\index{Lists}
\section{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}
\section{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}
\section{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\chapter{In-text Elements}
\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}
\section{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}
\section{Notations}\index{Notations}
\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}
\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}
\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}
\section{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}
\section{Examples}\index{Examples}
\section{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}
\section{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}
\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}
\section{Problems}\index{Problems}
\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

\chapter{Presenting Information}
\section{Table}\index{Table}
\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\section{Articles}
\section{Books}

\chapter{Text Chapter}
\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}
\section{Citation}\index{Citation}
\section{Lists}\index{Lists}
\section{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}
\section{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}
\section{Descriptions and Definitions}

\chapter{In-text Elements}
\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}
\section{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}
\section{Notations}\index{Notations}
\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}
\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}
\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}
\section{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}
\section{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}
\section{Examples}\index{Examples}
\section{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}
\section{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}
\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}
\section{Problems}\index{Problems}
\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

\chapter{Presenting Information}
\section{Table}\index{Table}
\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\section{Articles}
\section{Books}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love you so much! You have brilliantly solve my problem. When the book will be ended I will acknowledge your work in the last page. Thank you very much, for your time and work.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to change

```
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
```

to

```
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}%
```

This changes the mini TOC to only print chapter headings, and skip printing the section names, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Ok but... this is not honest. :-) In this way you cut several informations and do not solve the problem if the number of chapters is high.

Comment: Ok, but I already have a 7 page TOC, and did not see the point of having a 3 or 4 page mini TOC (not really mini is it :-). Your are right about the number of chapters, but I would figure out a way to have more parts if I had more than 16 chapters in a part. In any case, I have to write content, not play with TeX, so this was good enough for me.